# What kind of kanji is this?

Tags: kanji

[image]

There is 格 , then THAT character that i can't recognise, and then 内 .
Does someone have any idea of what that kanji is?

Comment: It's good to know that practically all fonts render a kanji in a square frame. It's highly unlikely that independent 内 has such a slender shape.

Answer (score 5):

It says 格納{かくのう}:

> ［名］(スル)物を一定の場所に納め入れること。「航空機を―する」 [(大辞泉)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A0%BC%E7%B4%8D-460656)

So the thin 糸 and 内 aren't separate characters, they're both part of 納.